# WP: How to display http://www.blog.mywebsite.com/ instead of http://www.mywebsite.com/blog?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, redirect, configuration

I have a wordpress website blog with url http://www.mywebsite.com/blog.

I don't want time being to install a multi-site option on wordpress. I would like to display http://www.blog.mywebsite.com/ instead of http://www.mywebsite.com/blog.

How to do it please ?

Answer (score 1):

Follow Below Steps :

- Create subdomain named http://www.blog.mywebsite.com/.
- Move wordpress blog folder to root.
- Replace all database field values from http://www.mywebsite.com/blog to http://www.blog.mywebsite.com/
- Try to access http://www.blog.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/
- You may need to update permalink from http://www.blog.mywebsite.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php